# Android: Bad call: specified pacakge **** under uid 10121 but it is really -1

Tags: android, eclipse, refactoring, package

I'm receiving a strange warning in my catlog when I run my app on my Samsung Galaxy Nexus (Android 4.3, rooted). I'm reading the log using logcat on the phone itself.

Background: recently I changed the package name for my project, using Eclipse's refactoring tool. I also went through each file and manually searched for the old package name; in particular, I updated all the references in AndroidManifest.xml. I also used Windows to manually search for the package name, found a few extraneous references, and updated them. There is NOWHERE in my project that references the old package name. I also cleaned and rebuilt the project from scratch.

Here's the warning:

```
11-25 14:20:35.684
Bad call: specified package com.old.package.name.appname under uid 10121 but it is really -1.
```

And the heading for the error, in the left column of catlog, is:

```
374
AppOps
```

This warning refreshes itself nearly instantly, sometimes multiple times per millisecond, and completely fills my log.

The odd thing is, when I install the app on my ASUS TF301 (4.2, rooted), I don't get this warning. When I run it on an emulator on my PC (launching from Eclipse), I don't get this warning.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After fooling around with it for a while, I noticed my logcat was showing the exact same thing even when the app was uninstalled, which led me to believe that the prior version (with the old package name) hadn't completely been uninstalled. So I restarted my phone and now the problem has disappeared. So, that's the solution: restart!