# Bad call: specified package com.google.android.play.games under uid 10238 but it is really 10062

Tags: android, google-play-services

This error happes on update TurnBasedMatch of google play services:

```
03-31 10:01:15.139 9179-9192/? W/AppOps: Bad call: specified package com.google.android.play.games under uid 10238 but it is really 10062
03-31 10:01:15.139 9179-9803/? W/AppOps: Bad call: specified package com.google.android.play.games under uid 10238 but it is really 10062
03-31 10:01:15.530 14236-4012/? E/Volley: [36392] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/turnbasedmatches/ChEKCQTE4Jn3xhYQAhACGAAgARCI66qZ-IqAntsB/turn?language=en_GB
03-31 10:01:15.532 14236-9563/? E/TurnBasedAgent: Failed to update match: null
```

Few hours before i was playing it, so it's more likely the error on the service's side. Rebooting the phone doesn't help me as was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201597/android-bad-call-specified-pacakge-under-uid-10121-but-it-is-really-1)

Comment: which version are you using ?

Comment: 3.6.27 (2647216-038)

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Restarting or reinstalling the app doesn't work for me either.

Comment: Seems like that's problem on their side, since it worked again after a few hours. i've got some [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36241749/delays-in-google-turn-based-multiplayer) problems with services so u may be having something like this too.

Comment: I have this problem on first install. But installing over the top of an existing install I do not have this problem. I am crashing when I hit this right after initializing Google Play Games at startup. I am looking for an answer still.